# Social timeline SQL logic

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am not experienced with MySQL genius so pardon me. I have 2 tables,

- TABLE 1 contains column names: `post_id (int, Auto Increment), post (varchar, user posts) and like (int) {like is incremented when a user likes the post e.g similar to facebook likes}`
- TABLE 2 contains column name: `id (int, Auto Increment) and post_id(int, foreign key to TABLE 1), user_id(varchar, User who liked this post)`

Now here is the tricky part for me, I want to select all posts from TABLE 1 and also indicate to the user which post has already been liked through TABLE 2 when a user requests for timeline, thus preventing the user from liking the the post again e.g how likes works on Instagram or any other social network i.e unlike if already liked.

What I tried using PHP and MySQL: Basically I retrieved all post from TABLE 1 based on the user retrieving a timeline and then I retrieved all data from TABLE 2 based on the user who needs the timeline, then I check to see if there is a match with TABLE 1's returned data and TABLE 2's returned data. With each returned post in the timeline I tag 1 to indicate in code the incoming post has been liked and 0 for not liked and then I display the appropriate UI flow to user in doing so I can make sure the user does not like the same post twice.

**Selecting all from TABLE 2**

```
SELECT * FROM `TABLE_2` WHERE `username` = :username
```

**Selecting from TABLE 1**

```
SELECT * FROM `TABLE_1` WHERE `reporter` IN (SELECT `destination_id` FROM `followers` WHERE `source_id` = :username)
         UNION
         SELECT * FROM `TABLE_1` WHERE `reporter` = :username
         ORDER BY `created_at` DESC LIMIT 20
```

The above query returns a users timeline based on another logic and certain other factors

Now I compare both returned data from TABLE 1 and TABLE 2

```
if($likes != NULL)
{
   $count = 0;
   foreach($returnedtimeline["posts"] as $single)
   {
       if(array_search($likes[$count], $single) == "id")
       {
              $returnedtimeline["posts"][$count]["liked"] = 1;
              $count++;
       }else{
              $returnedtimeline["posts"][$count]["liked"] = 0;
              $count++;
            }
  }
```

But I believe there is a better way I can do this through one direct query than multiple queries because my methods has large disadvantages with time, amount of data and processing power of the server.

Comment: Always include what you tried. Never use tags that do not apply to your question. Are you using MySQL or SQL Server?

Comment: Can we see what you tried code wise either in your post or in a fiddle?

Comment: This is one of the rare cases where you are asking for a "not exists" query. You want all records from table 1 where not exists a record in table 2. In the simplest (inefficient) form: select * from table1 where post_id not in (select post_id from table2 where user_id=$theuser)

Comment: John Conde: SQL means "Structured Query Language", not "Microsoft SQL Server". It is on-topic. This is a question about SQL use on the MySQL engine through a PHP interface.

Comment: @kainaw Check out the edit history - it was tagged with `sql-server` earlier

Comment: @Jeff That makes a hell of a lot more sense.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you just want join in your select, to return columns from both tables at once. Something like:

```
select
    post_id,
    case when "Table 2".post_id is null then 0 else 1 end as UserHasLiked
from "Table 1"
left join "Table 2" on "Table 1".post_id = "Table 2".post_id
```

I'm not a MYSQL user, so the syntax may be a little off, but it should be pretty close I think.

Comment: This will return all records that have a like. I believe that he wants all records that the user has not liked.

Comment: @kainaw That's not my understanding of the issue - from what I understand the OP needs the liked ones as well so that the "unlike" option can be displayed

Comment: Yea @kainaw that's exactly what i want.

Comment: @AlexDavies Sorry, are you saying you want to select all the records that the user has not liked (as kainaw suggests), or all the records (as in my answer)?

Comment: @Jeff I want to return all the records but indicate which singular record had been like or liked.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT *,
CASE WHEN likes.face_id = persona.face_id THEN '1' ELSE '0' END liked,
CASE WHEN dislikes.face_id = persona.face_id THEN '1' ELSE '0' END disliked,
CASE WHEN comments.face_id = persona.face_id THEN '1' ELSE '0' END commented
FROM persona, likes, dislikes, comments
RIGHT JOIN tagged ON tagged.phone_id = :pid WHERE persona.face_id = tagged.face_id
```

works like magic.